# What is the maximum versions a page can have in AEM?

Tags: aem

Is there a limit to the no. of versions a content item can have in AEM? I want to retain all the versions of my page. As in, unlimited.

Want to know if AEM has a limit internally after which it automatically removes older versions?

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is **not recommended** but you can disable the version manager by configuring the `versionmanager.purgingEnabled` to `false`. You will need to configure this as described in the document below:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/deploy/configuring/version-purging.html#Version Manager

> Retaining lots of versions will gradually slow down your instance and result in poor authoring performance as the storage (Tar or Mongo) will grow large with stale data.

It is normally recommended to retain versions by a fixed number of days or fixed number of version counts.

> For performance reasons, it is better to backup your AEM instance for older archived versions and rely on a restore function to access those versions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know what is the limit in AEM? Is it based on no. of versions or time? as in 200 versions or 200 days, after which AEM does auto purging.

Also, when its purging, how many items does it purge, is it, one at a time, after the limit is hit?

Eg: if limit is 200 and we have achieved 200 versions, does it just autopurge one item to make it 199 and so on?

Also, where can we configure the version retain configuration?

Comment: Based on the configuration, it is an `OR` condition between versions and time. For your example, if number of versions exceed 200 then 201st version will delete 1 oldest version so you will end up with 200 versions max. Same goes for time, regardless of number of versions if the oldest version is older than 200 days it will be deleted. Default is 30 for both values.

Answer (score 1):

I was asking this question once to Adobe DayCare and received the similar response like in i.net post - it is possible to disable purging the versioning of the page however it comes with the risk of authoring performance issues - pages can start loading very slowly.
The solutions that were suggested (depending on the requirements):

- backing up an instance, which is not the best one if you need to be able to retrieve or compare old content anytime, recover if needed; the disadvantage is that all copy of instance needs to be stored and it needs to be repeated from time to time (when you notice performance issues)
- designing and implementing a custom solution with an additional instance that would be responsible for storing these versions - I have no much details on that solution however as I understood, it would require deep analysis how it can be done
- if the access to previous content is needed only for historical reasons (no need to retrieve it and publish once again) then taking use of the page to PDF extraction mechanism and storing history in DAM or another place; you can then also consider saving to PDF screenshot all page with design (not content only), presenting different browser breakpoints, annotations, etc. depending on requirements

Comment: No, this would be for rollback purposes and not just for historical data.
thanks for the info.